# Peskin and Schroeder QFT Eq.(12.66), the Renormalization Group equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, correlation-functions, greens-functions

I am troubled for the derivation of Eq.$(12.66)$ on Peskin and Schroeder's QFT book.
$$
\left[p \frac{\partial}{\partial p}-\beta(\lambda) \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}+2-2 \gamma(\lambda)\right] G^{(2)}(p)=0. \tag{12.66}
$$
Actually, DelCrosB had derived this in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/291925/). But I am still troubled for some points. In DelCrosB's derivation, he starts from
$$G^{(2)}(p)=\frac{i}{p^2}g(-p^2/M^2). \tag{12.65}$$
and
$$p\frac{\partial G^{(2)}(p)}{\partial p}=-2G^{(2)}(p)-\frac{2i}{M^2}g'(-p^2/M^2)$$
$$M\frac{\partial G^{(2)}(p)}{\partial M}=\frac{2i}{M^2}g'(-p^2/M^2).$$
where we need to note that the $p$ in $p\frac{\partial}{\partial p}$ is $p=\sqrt{-p^2}$. If we eliminate the $g^\prime$, we can obtain Eq.$(12.66)$.

My question is, why the $g'(-p^2/M^2)$ in $p\frac{\partial G^{(2)}(p)}{\partial p}$ and $M\frac{\partial G^{(2)}(p)}{\partial M}$ are same? Does this means that
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial p}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial M}? $$
But I think $p^2=M^2$ is the Renormalization condition (According to Eq.$(12.30)$ in the book). In general case, shouldn't $p\neq M$? How to understand this relation?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very simple math problem. I somehow stuck in previously.

If we denote $$y=-\frac{p^2}{M^2} $$
the $g^\prime(y)$ in $p\frac{\partial G^2(p,M)}{\partial p}$ and $M\frac{\partial G^2(p,M)}{\partial M}$ is just
$$g^\prime(y)=\frac{d g}{d y} $$
so this term is identical for $p\frac{\partial G^2(p,M)}{\partial p}$ and $M\frac{\partial G^2(p,M)}{\partial M}$.